# shuffle core data attributes on a tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, tableview, shuffle

In my swift code it loads an attribute from core data entity Song attribute title. It is in a relationship with entity singer with its destination being singer. I want to shuffle the contents of what is displayed in the tableview. What I have now is causing the error of

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton length]: unrecognized sel

```
class SongsVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    var songs = [Song]()

    init(index: Int) {
        self.index = index
        singer = singers[index]
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }


 @objc func shuffleButtonPressed(){
        
  
        singer = singers[index]
        
        singer?.songs?.shuffled()
    }
```

Comment: That error is about your UI setup, it's not a Core Data error. Somewhere you have a button and you're trying to find out its `length` as if it was an array. But that's not in the code you posted, so it's impossible to say where.